# Method with @Receiver AndroidAnnotation in Service (extends FirebaseMessagingService) not called

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-annotations

My `service` shows `notification` with cancel and accept `action`. And I want to use `@Receiver` (androidannotation libs) inside my `service` to handle cancel action. Here is my code:

```
private PendingIntent setupCancelIntent(String id, int notificationId) {
    //set up pending intent for cancel action
    Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(CANCEL_ACTION);
    dismissIntent.putExtra(Constant.ID, id);
    dismissIntent.putExtra(Constant.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notificationId, dismissIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

@Receiver(actions = CANCEL_ACTION)
public void actionCancel(@Receiver.Extra(Constant.ID) String id,
        @Receiver.Extra(Constant.NOTIFICATION_ID) int notificationId, Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Cancel action " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (notificationId != -1) {
        NotificationManager manager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(notificationId);
    }
}
```

My notification is showed, but when press cancel button, the actionCancel method is not called. What am I missed!

Comment: Are you sure your `Service` is alive when the broadcast is sent?

Comment: Hi @MikeM. Am I missed something when use `@Receiver` annotation in a `Service` that extends from `FirebaseMessagingService`?? Is this problem?

Comment: As for the deleted comment: just because a `Notification` is showing, it doesn't mean the `Service` is still running. How are you determining that? Also, did you start the right class; i.e., the one that ends with an underscore? Does this work if you use an actual Receiver, instead of the annotation? Have you tried testing with a static Receiver in the manifest, to make sure the broadcast is being sent? I don't know of any abnormal behavior particular to `FirebaseMessagingService`.

Comment: Im sorry for my unsure comment. My first time using androidannotation lib, it's really cool. I have tested with normal receiver, it worked. but with androidannotation `@Receiver` (inside service) or `@EReceiver` + `@ReceiverAction` (public class), it didn't work. I will try again to find where my mistake.

Comment: My code worked with `@EReceiver` and `@ReceiverAction`. My mistake is calling `new Intent(this, MISSING_UNDERSCORED.class);`. But about `@Receiver`, it still not working. Thanks much @Mike.

Comment: Hmm, well, if it worked for the static Receiver, I would say that it really sounds like your `Service` might've stopped before the broadcast, which means the Receiver would be gone. I've not used `Firebase`, but their `Service` sounds like one that would be designed to run just long enough to handle a message. You might check when it stops. Also, I would point out that you don't have to cancel that `Notification` from the `Service`. If the static Receiver worked for ya, you can just do it there. All you need is the ID.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. In settings, I see no running `service`, only 1 process, maybe I need to find how `Firebase` service working. About clear notification, sure, I send Id to my `broadcast` via intent. :)